# Animate icon in different Array selectorID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have six selectorIDs and need to animate them separately when pointer hovers on each. I'm trying to use array but it doesn't work.

I want like in: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alicera/kVHbV/817/) but there are six buttons

I place each of the selectorIDs in div. So, when hover, it animates based on which ID has pointer on hover, as follows:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="ani1">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Banana
...
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="ani2">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Blogspot Toko Online
...
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="ani3">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Apple
...
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="ani4">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Mango
...
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="ani5">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Durian
...
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="ani6">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Pineapple
...
</div>
```

Here's the script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
    var ani=array("#ani1","#ani2","#ani3","#ani4","#ani5","#ani6");
    $("ani").hover(function(){
        var $icon = $( this ).find( ".fa-refresh" ),
            animateClass = "icon-animate";
            $icon.addClass( animateClass );
            window.setTimeout( function(){
                $icon.removeClass( animateClass );
            }, 2000 );
    });   
});
</script>
```

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to share my own version. Hope you like it!

**HTML :**

```
<button id="ani1" class='btn btn-success'><i class="icon-refresh"></i> Click Here</button>
<button id="ani2" class='btn btn-success'><i class="icon-refresh"></i> Click Here</button>
<button id="ani3" class='btn btn-success'><i class="icon-refresh"></i> Click Here</button>
<button id="ani4" class='btn btn-success'><i class="icon-refresh"></i> Click Here</button>
```

**CSS :**

```
.icon-refresh-animate {
    animation-name: rotateThis;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
} 
@keyframes rotateThis {
    from { transform: scale( 1 ) rotate( 0deg );   }
    to   { transform: scale( 1 ) rotate( 360deg ); }
}
```

**JQUERY :**

```
$( document ).ready( function($) { 
    var custom_timeout = ( function() {
    var timers = {};
    return function ( callback, ms, uniqueId ) {
        if ( !uniqueId ) {
            uniqueId = "Don't call this twice without a uniqueId";
        }
        if ( timers[uniqueId] ) {
            clearTimeout ( timers[uniqueId] );
        }
        timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout( callback, ms );
      };
    })();
    //#ani1,#ani2,#ani3,#ani4,#ani5,#ani6
    $(".btn-success").mouseover(function(){ 
        $(".btn-success").find( ".icon-refresh" ).removeClass( "icon-refresh-animate" );
        var $icon = $( this ).find( ".icon-refresh" );
        var animateClass = "icon-refresh-animate"; 
        $icon.addClass( animateClass );  
        // setTimeout is to indicate some async operation
        custom_timeout( function() {
            $icon.removeClass( animateClass );
        }, 2000 );

    }).mouseleave (function(){
        custom_timeout( function() {
            $(".btn-success").find( ".icon-refresh" ).removeClass( "icon-refresh-animate" );
        }, 200 );
    });  
});
```

[image]

[jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonypagaycarbon/r5xyo6j5/)

Comment: Use `$(".btn-success").mouseover(function(){`  Or `$("#ani1,#ani2,#ani3,#ani4,#ani5,#ani6").mouseover(function(){`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mm3a181r/1/).

Well `$("ani")` will search for an `<ani>` object, to search for your array, use `$(ani)` instead.

Also, arrays in javascript are defined using the `myArray = [elem1,elem2..]` format.

Also, you had a scope issue in your `setTimeout()`

In your case, your code should like like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ani = ["#ani1", "#ani2", "#ani3", "#ani4", "#ani5", "#ani6"];
    ani = ani.join(","); //#any1,any2,any3..
    $(ani).hover(function () {
        var $icon = $(this).find(".fa-refresh"),
            animateClass = "icon-animate";
        $icon.addClass(animateClass);
        (function (icon, animateClass) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                icon.removeClass(animateClass);
            }, 2000);
        })($icon, animateClass);
    });
});
```

Comment: it's still no animating :(

Comment: You had an scope issue in your setTimeout, any `anonymous function` set as a `setTimeout` callback executes in the window context, so when you said `$icon.removeClass()` you were actually calling the `window.$icon` object, which doesn't exist, I fixed it for you, see the updated answer.

Comment: sorry, it still not working ... I didn't change my code but copy-paste your example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69366/discussion-between-gkol-and-rou).

Answer (score 2):

I would make `ani` a class instead of ids, then just do `$('.ani').hover(function()....` like the below.

**Note** that I am using sudo `CSS` since none was posted but it gets the point across.

Remember you can always get the individual elements by class too by using `eq()`. For example, `$('.ani:eq(0)').hide();` would hide the first panel, `$('.ani:eq(1)').hide();` would hide the second, etc...

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.ani').hover(function(){
        var $icon = $( this ).find( ".fa-refresh" );
            $icon.addClass( "icon-animate" );
      
            /* use `mouseout` later instead of a timeout here, unless want the icon to stop spinning after a few seconds of hovering
           
            window.setTimeout( function(){
                $icon.removeClass( "icon-animate" );
            }, 2000 ); 
            */
    });  
  
  $( ".ani" ).mouseout(function() {
      $( this ).find( ".fa-refresh" ).removeClass( "icon-animate" );
  });
});
```

```css
.ani{
  width:150px;
  height:75px;
  background-color:#cccccc;
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-left:15px;
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
}

.fa-refresh{
  float:right;
  
}



.icon-animate {
    font-size:14px;
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
    
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/css/animations.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel panel-default ani">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Banana
...
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default ani">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Blogspot Toko Online
...
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default ani" >
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Apple
...
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default ani">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Mango
...
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default ani">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Durian
...
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default ani">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Pineapple
...
</div>
```

Comment: it animates two object in one time

Comment: @gkol only if you hover over one item then move to another. That is because of your setTimeout function. If you want, you could remove the class immediately when the mouse moves off the element. Is that what you need?

Comment: @gkol I removed the timeout favoring the "remove on mouseout" method. You only need the timeout if you want the icon to stop spinning after a few seconds of hovering.

Comment: thanks, but it's already solved by @Anthony and it works well on my web page. I do appreciate for all of your help. ^_^